# How to allow sign in with devise if user is already authenticated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

There's an App which creates a new user when you first time open the site (if you don't have a cookie). Also you can sign in as different user. The problem is Devise doesn't allow to sign in as already authenticated user. Even if I override `require_no_authentication` in `SessionsController` warden still remembers the user through session.

I do aware about [guest user pattern](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user) but there's no guest user. The app is intended to create real user accounts and allow to sign in as another users.

So the question is should I create new Warden strategy and if so, what checks shall I do there? Or there's another way?

Answer (score 0):

Just reset the session in the desired action. You can just make the first line be `reset_session`, or make it a before filter, like so:

```
before_filter :deauthorize_user, only: [ :some_action ]

def deauthorize_user
  reset_session
end
```

Comment: I've thought about it but in that case if user makes mistake with password we need to create a new account because CSRF token will be invalid on second request and thus we need to get new token before next attempt (we use AJAX for sign-in).